# Scatter Plot Binary Data Color Coded Points from Data Labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to use matplotlib.pyplot.scatter to create a scatter plot similar to the picture below from data in a dataframe with a header that is formatted similar to the table here where all the points for a given sample are colored based on the label in the first column of the data and a point is only plotted for each gene with a value of 1 - no point for the genes with a 0 value:

| label | gene a | gene b | gene c | gene d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

[image]

Note: my sample data does not match my sample scatter plot output.

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong with your attempts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After melting your dataframe to a long format you can draw a matrix with seaborn's [`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("ticks")

df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/q/70856944/14277722')[0]
df['sample'] = df.index
df = df.melt(['label','sample'])

g = sns.relplot(
    data=df,
    x="variable", y="sample", hue="label", size="value",
    hue_norm=(-1, 1), palette='tab10',
    height=6, sizes=(10, 300), size_norm=(0, 1)
)
g.set(xlabel="Genes", ylabel="Samples",
    #   ylim=[df['sample'].max()+.5, df['sample'].min()-.5]  # uncomment to invert the y-axis
);
```

[image: matrix plot]

With the melted dataframe you can access `plt.scatter` directly from pandas but I think you have to add your own custom legend for the labels.

```
df.plot(x='variable', y='sample', s=(df.value+0.1) * 300, kind='scatter',
        ylim=[df['sample'].max()+.5, df['sample'].min()-.5], # uncomment to flip y-axis
        figsize=(7,6), c='label', cmap='coolwarm', colorbar=False
);
```

[image: pandas matrix plot]